# How to update stackingestimator parameters when the model pipeline was created by the older version of sckit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, pipeline, tpot

I have a model pipeline stored in pkl file which was created by the `sckit-learn 0.19`. I'm trying to update the missing parameters that need for the new version of `sckit-learn 0.22`.

The pipeline looks like the following:

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('stackingestimator-1', StackingEstimator(estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='mse', max_depth=2, max_features=None,
           max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
           min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=8,
           min_samples_split=7, min_weight_fraction_lea...positive=False, precompute='auto', random_state=42,
       selection='cyclic', tol=0.1, verbose=0))])
```

In `sckit-learn 0.22`, they have added a new parameter `'ccp_alpha'`in the `DecisionTreeRegressor`. So, I need to add this new parameter into every `DecisionTreeRegressor` used in the pipeline. I have tried using the `set_param_recursive` in `tpot`, but it didn't add the missing attribute into the estimator:

```
set_param_recursive(pipeline_steps=model.steps, parameter='ccp_alpha', value=0.0)
```

It will return the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'ccp_alpha'
```

Is there a solution to update missing parameters added in the new version?